# Code doesn't get syntax colored

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noticed that [code snippets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/any-reliable-polygon-normal-calculation-code) do not get syntax coloring like stackoverflow. Instead the whole chunk appears black and white. Is it something I've done wrong or is this a massive missing feature?

Comment: I have noticed this as well. What's curious is that it *does* appear colored correctly when I (for example) attempt to edit somebody's post.

Comment: Specifically, if I edit the post and make an actual change, then wait a few moments, it becomes colored.

Comment: @josh we're not exactly sure why this was never enabled, seems like an obvious thing, we're enabling it now

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a server-side issue. On StackOverflow, code snippets in questions or answers have a special `prettyprint` class, *eg.* `<pre class="lang-c prettyprint"> ... </pre>` whereas on Gamedev the code snippets are served as `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>`.

Answer (score 2):

Code will now be styled by default - [look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/3) if you need to manually override a specific syntax.

Comment: It appears to still be an issue on the /review page.